# No DataContext for Array element (Xamarin .NET MAUI C#)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

The part of the app I am struggling with is that I am creating an array through user input, when the user inputs this new element to the array they must choose a name and description. The item of the list is clickable and will go to a new page, on this new page I want an header (label) to display the clicked on items name, however it is not displaying this and just displays as blank, in visual studio there is a green line underneath the snippet of code I have shown, when hovering over this is displays "No DataContext found for Text" I have attached screenshots underneath of how the app operates.[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm trying to reference an Array elements Name. I believe this has something to do with it not being able to find the array as I am not referencing it anywhere however I'm unsure on how to do this? The class is stored in the models folder, It has the "Text" as a variable, I'm not sure if it gets which element of the array I am wanting to use? Here is a snippet of my code.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="CadentPPE1CheckApp.Views.ItemDetailPage"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CadentPPE1CheckApp.ViewModels"  
         xmlns:model="clr-namespace:CadentPPE1CheckApp.Models"  
         Title="{Binding Title}">


<StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
    <Label Text="Registration ID:" FontSize="Medium" />
    <Label x:DataType="model:Item" Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="Medium"/>
    <Label Text="PPE1 Check Status:" FontSize="Medium" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="Small"/>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding EItems}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="10"
              RowDefinitions="Auto, *"
              ColumnDefinitions="Auto, *">
                <Label Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="{Binding Name}"
                   FontAttributes="Bold" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="2"
                   Text="{Binding SerialNo}"
                   VerticalOptions="End" />
                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="3"
                   Text="{Binding ExpiryDate}"
                   VerticalOptions="End" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

This is the code for the model I am binding too:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

And this is where I am setting Text Value

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Spacing="3" Padding="15">
        <Label Text="Text" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Text="Description" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Editor Text="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoSize="TextChanges" FontSize="Medium" Margin="0" />
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Text="Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
            <Button Text="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

view model:

```
using CadentPPE1CheckApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace CadentPPE1CheckApp.ViewModels
{
[QueryProperty(nameof(ItemId), nameof(ItemId))]
public class ItemDetailViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string itemId;
    private string text;
    private string description;
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Text
    {
        get => text;
        set => SetProperty(ref text, value);
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get => description;
        set => SetProperty(ref description, value);
    }

    public string ItemId
    {
        get
        {
            return itemId;
        }
        set
        {
            itemId = value;
            LoadItemId(value);
        }
    }

    public async void LoadItemId(string itemId)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = await DataStore.GetItemAsync(itemId);
            Id = item.Id;
            Text = item.Text;
            Description = item.Description;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to Load Item");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  If you don't post the relevant code there is very little we can do to help you.  *Describing* the code is not an effective substitute for actually posting the code.  And posting images of code or errors is not allowed

Comment: is this not the relevant code in the snippet?

Comment: No.  1) it's an image, not a code snippet, 2) it gives no indication of where specifically the problem is, 3) you haven't posted the relevant code for the model you are binding to

Comment: You’ve posted two sets of XAML.  Which one is the problem?  Where are you setting the BindingContext?

Comment: The first snippet is the problem, where I am using Text = Binding Text, it is not showing the value of "Text". Which I assume is because it doesn't know the value of Text? This is why I am asking, how do I give it a value, As I click on the Item in the list, I want the name (value of "Text" for that array element) to be displayed on the page it takes you too, this is just an edited version of the .forms template.

Comment: Do you have a Text property on your VM?  Again, since you have not posted that code it’s difficult to help

Comment: I have added the view model code, there is a Text property that is being set to item.Text

Comment: then why is `x:DataType="model:Item"` and not `ItemDetailViewModel`?

Comment: Unsure about that, however I have corrected this and it still hasn't worked I set it to local:ItemDetailViewModel however still nothing.

Comment: if you want to post your solution somewhere I can download it I'll take a quick look.  Interactively debugging via a comment thread isn't very effective

Comment: I think you’ve mixed up two different types of models. Specifically, what is in the array element, vs. what is not.  What is in the xaml collectionview, vs what is not. Please copy your solution to a new folder, then remove EVERYTHING not needed  to show this bug. Since it is a single field that is bugged, there should be very little code in the project. If you still can’t see the problem, then edit code and images in question to match.

Comment: I redid this section of code an have managed to problem solve it, I'm unsure of where I went wrong, but thanks for the help.

Comment: Do additem page and detail page bind to the same viewmodel? And when you navigate whether create a new viewmodel which cause the text blank.